# Как отменить DELETE, запретив удалять последнюю запись в таблице

Tags: mysql, sql, триггер

Пусть имеется таблица пользователей `users`, например, которые используются для входа в административную часть сайта. Как запретить удаление (`DELETE`) последней записи таблицы? Т.е. в таблице всегда должен оставаться минимум один пользователь. Попытка его удаления должна завершаться неудачей не зависимо от текущих привилегий.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO users VALUES
(1, 'first'),
(2, 'second'),
(3, 'third');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для решения данной задачи удобно воспользоваться триггером `BEFORE DELETE` на таблицу `users`.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER check_last_users BEFORE DELETE ON users
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET @total := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users);
  IF @total <= 1 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'DELETE canceled'; 
  END IF;
END//
```

Триггер подсчитывает количество строк в таблице и если оно меньше или равно единицы запрещает дальнейшее выполнение запроса путем генерации сигнала при помощи `SIGNAL SQLSTATE`. Здесь мы воспользовались сигналом 45000, предназначенного для пользовательских ошибок, не подлежащих перехвату.

```
mysql> DELETE FROM users LIMIT 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> DELETE FROM users LIMIT 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,01 sec)

mysql> DELETE FROM users LIMIT 1;
ERROR 1644 (45000): DELETE canceled
```

**UPDATE**

По совету [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike) дополняю ответ вариантом, ориентированным на объемные таблицы, в которых вычисление `COUNT(*)` слишком трудоемко и часто требует полного сканирования таблицы (особенно в случае InnoDB). Прием основан на сравнении минимального и максимального идентификатора `id`, если эти значения совпадают, очевидно, что в таблице лишь одна запись.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER check_last_users BEFORE DELETE ON users
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET @block := (SELECT MIN(id) = MAX(id) FROM users);
  IF @block = 1 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'DELETE canceled'; 
  END IF;
END//
```

Comment: Это не жирно будет -> `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users` ?

Comment: @Visman Это иллюстрация, можно запросить последних двух пользователей LIMIT 2  и проверить, что их два, а не один. Можно придумать другой критерий. Я исходил из того, что в таблице не много пользователей (речь о системе администрирования, где пользователей редко больше сотни). Если вы приведете альтернативный вариант, ориентированный на большую таблицу, где COUNT(*) слишком дорог, будет очень здорово, с удовольствием плюсану и зачту ответ.

Comment: для больших таблиц при наличии первичного ключа надо получать min(id) и max(id) - они получаются моментально по индексу. и сравнивать эти id между собой

Comment: Вы не учитываете возможность DELETE FROM users - когда удалятся все записи, в т.ч. и последняя. Т.е. проверять надо, что будет в таблице ПОСЛЕ удаления, а не что было в ней до. С синтаксисом MySQL в части триггеров не знаком, поэтому свой ответ предлагать не буду, но, думаю, переписать ваш вариант несложно.

Comment: @minamoto спасибо за замечание, попробовал выполнить DELETE FROM users, в случае когда таблица имеет одну и две записи. Триггер сработал в обоих случаях - видимо MySQL удаляет через внутренний курсор.

Comment: @Mike, спасибо, за вариант, если не возражаете, дополнил им ответ.